# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [index.jsp] at line [38]

Tags: tomcat9

My apache homepage is throwing the following exceptions. I can visit manager and other pages through URL though. This is not even my code and couldn't find any specific solution to this.I didn't make any changes to default settings and it was working fine the last i checked.
I mostly use it through eclipse IDE for development and it's working fine from there(because i don't have to visit homepage from there).

```
Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing [index.jsp] at line [38]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [index.jsp] at line [38]

35:     <body>
36:         <div id="wrapper">
37:             <div id="navigation" class="curved container">
38:                 <span id="nav-home"><a href="${tomcatUrl}">Home</a></span>
39:                 <span id="nav-hosts"><a href="${tomcatDocUrl}">Documentation</a></span>
40:                 <span id="nav-config"><a href="${tomcatDocUrl}config/">Configuration</a></span>
41:                 <span id="nav-examples"><a href="${tomcatExamplesUrl}">Examples</a></span>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:625)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:499)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELResolver
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:666)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:427)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELResolver
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.createELResolver(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:121)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.createELContext(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:90)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.getELContext(PageContextImpl.java:707)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:692)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:140)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELResolver
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.createELResolver(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:121)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.createELContext(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:90)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.getELContext(PageContextImpl.java:707)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:692)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:140)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)`enter code here`
```

Comment: Update: For some reason i can't use Expression language in my tomcat 9 , it throws the 'failed to initialised org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImp' .

Answer (score 0):

It seems tomcat9 doesn't get along with jdk8(as i found out). Tried with jdk12(and also with openjdk12) and it worked!. Didn't try with jdk9, jdk10 and jdk11. Now i recollect facing the same issues the first time i installed tomcat9 when i was using jdk8 and it didn't work(only the homepage).The supported java version for [Apache9](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) states `8 and later` hence i suspect this  to be a specific issue of mine( hit me in the comment if you faced this too).